# Wordpress rewrite rule regex

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm trying to pass a detail as a get variable using the Wordpress Rewrite Rule API. I'm not great with regex and it's driving me mad. I have tried every combination of the below and I'm not getting anywhere:

```
function dcc_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%propref%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_tags', 10, 0);

function dcc_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^/[^/]*/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?p=2&propref=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);
```

The url structure is mysite.com/page/get-variable/. I'm just trying to pass the last bit between the slashes as the get variable "propref". Most variations I've tried, it says it can't find the page or drops the last section of slashes.

Comment: Have a look at the `query_vars` filter, `post_link` and `add_query_arg`

Comment: sorry, but none of those are any help.